# Search exclude project level node_modules, but not nested node_modules

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to figure out how to exclude the project-level `node_modules`folder from search, but **include** *nested* `node_modules` in my `src` folder.

Here is my directory structure:

[image]

My `search.exclude` in my vscode settings file:

[image]

And my `.gitignore`:

[image]

`Cmd + Shift + F` and I search for something I know is in a file in my `src/node_modules/*` folder and the search does not find it.

What am I doing wrong?